# Java DOM: Indent documentation element with multiline paragraph

Tags: java, dom

To indent the XML Document output in Java (DOM), I use the following code as everyone knows,

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(parent), new StreamResult(sw));
```

It works without any issues for smaller text content. But when a large text-content present in my element/node (especially I have huge paragraph inside my 'documentation' element), it is not indented properly. I'm getting the output as follows,

```
<xs:annotation>
       <xs:documentation>"The value of sysUpTime at the time of the last change of
        the (whole) interface stack.  A change of the interface
        stack is defined to be any creation, deletion, or change in
        value of any instance of ifStackStatus.  If the interface
        stack has been unchanged since the last re-initialization of
        the local network management subsystem, then this object
        contains a zero value."</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

Please help me with the proper formatting/indentation for these kind of paragraphs.

I expect the output like,

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
        "The value of sysUpTime at the time of the last change of
        the (whole)interface stack.  A change of the interface
        stack is defined to be any creation, deletion, or change in
        value of any instance of ifStackStatus.If the interface
        stack has been unchanged since the last re-initialization of
        the local network management subsystem, then this object
        contains a zero value."
     </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

Thanks in  advance!

Comment: what do you mean "not indented properly"?

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Please see the edit above. I have included the expected output.

Comment: I think you need to create SAX transformer and implement the events that handle start/end element.  I tried to create a working example, but it was too complex for me and the net seriously lack examples or tutorials